# How to allow users to see content of a folder through url in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I would like to show the files in a folder to the visitors of my website. I am using zf2. If I try to access the folder through url, I am getting the error "A 404 error occurred Page not found." For example, my folder is test and I am trying like this "https://example.com/public/test" or "https://example.com/test".

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is more secure to work within the ZF2 architecture, read the directory and then present to the user.  You may also use rewrite rules, but for that answer you need to identify the server you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I can read the directory and then show it to the user. But, I have the following criteria.
1) Visitor sends a request (e.g. https://example.com/generate) which will be generating multiple files in a folder (say 'test').
2) I want to show the files instantly by providing an anchor link to the folder "test" (https://example.com/test) in the same page (https://example.com/generate)

Since I cannot run a second request while the first request is still being processed. I would like to give direct link to the folder as mentioned in the 2nd point. Please suggest.